# Где можно бесплатно скачать TTF шрифты?

Tags: шрифты, ttf

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, сайт (или сайты), где можно бесплатно скачать TTF шрифты. В данный момент ищу шрифт helvetica.ttf, но пока нашел только Helvetica_Cyrillic_Bold.ttf. А мне нужен именно обычный, не жирный.

Comment: Интересует сайт где можно скачать различные шрифты бесплатно, чтобы можно было пользоваться им постоянно. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос можно закрывать! Остановился на сайте http://www.xfont.ru/. Очень хорошая подборка шрифтов!

Answer (score 0):

Для вебсайтов часто используют [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts).